# Rspec - Module inside class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, rspec, module

I have tried several way to rspec the 'to_type' function. The fact that it is inside the class means that only the class should be able to call it right? I've tried to include the Class in my rspec but the module "Format" is still not recognized. Any ideas how I can rspec this method 'to_type' from the module?

```
class Loom::Lma < Loom::Base
  module Format
    STANDARD_FORMATS = {
      1 => '0',
      2 => '13.4',
    }
    def to_type(format)
      # type is calculated here then return type
      # for instance
      return :date
    end
    module_function :to_type
  end
  def initialize()
    #init stuff
  end
  def otherstuff()
        #another function
  end
end
```

RSPEC

```
it 'type should not be :date' do
   include Loom::Lma
   Format.to_type('some string format').should_not eq(:date)
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to put that module into a class not the other way around?
Anyway, you can access to_type like this:

```
Loom::Lma::Format.to_type()
```